# php change filename from usb disk

Tags: php, linux, mamp

The operating system is macOS. The local server environment is MAMP, and the usb path is `/Volumes/USB_DISK`.

Now I want to detect file change in usb disk and change it's name,like change `1.jpeg` to `a1.jpeg`,the code:

```
function getFreshImage($dir, $prefix){
    $iterator = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME);
    foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
        $fullName = basename($iterator->current());
        $name = basename($iterator->current(), '.jpeg');
        if (strpos($name, '.') === false && strpos($name, $prefix) === false) {    
            $newName = $prefix.$fullName;
            $bool = rename($dir.$fullName, $dir.$newName);  // always return false here 
        }
    }
}


$fname = '/Volumes/USB_DISK';
$prefix = 'a';
getFreshImage($fname, $prefix);     // add prefix to fresh image
```

I checked the directory, and the privileges is `777`, anyone know how to do with this, should I config php.ini or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems  I made a foolish mistake, I try it in the common line  `php scanFile.php`, and it shows

```
Warning: rename(/Volumes/USB_DISKa1.jpeg,/Volumes/USB_DISKba1.jpeg): No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/capture/scanFile.php on line 36
falseba3.jpeg<br><br>
```

so I find that I passed a wrong `dir` params, the `fname` should be

```
$fname = '/Volumes/USB_DISK/';
```

just a `slash`, now it works.